# Dynamically move a div above a list element using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this html layout as shown below. I want to dynamically move this div before the list element using pure Javascript. Can anyone tell me way to do this.

Thanks in advance

```
    <ol class="chapter-list" style="width: 469px">
        <li data-time="0" id="0"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 88%;">Chapter 1</span></li>

        <li data-time="104" id="104"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 88%;">Chapter 2</span></li>

        <li data-time="235" id="235"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 88%;">Chapter 3</span></li>

        <li data-time="309" id="309"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 88%;">Chapter 4</span></li>

        <li data-time="406" id="406"><span style="display: inline-block; width: 88%;">Chapter 5</span></li>
    </ol>

    <div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Nope. I did't try anything else. I couldn't find any good solution for this yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `insertBefore` method to of dom node element like the following:

```
var divEl, refEl, parentEl;

//get the div element
divEl = document.getElementById("mydiv");
//get the parent of the div element
parentEl = divEl.parentElement;
//get the referrence el before which you want to insert the div by quering the parent node
refEl = parentEl.querySelector('.chapter-list');
//Insert the div element before the reference el
parentEl.insertBefore(divEl, refEl);
```

Answer (score 0):

A combination of a little DOM traversal, `removeChild`, and `insertBefore` can do it. First fetch the element:

```
var below = document.getElementById('mydiv');
```

Then figure out the first element above it:

```
var above = below.previousSibling;
while(above && above.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    above = above.previousSibling;
```

(There is a `previousElementSibling` property that could also do the job, but I don’t know how long that’s been around.)

Then we can remove it from the document and reinsert it above the list:

```
below.parentNode.removeChild(below);
above.parentNode.insertBefore(below, above);
```

---

<sub><sup>In case you need a golfed version:`!function(n,d,b,p){for(b=d[n];b&&b.nodeType-1;b=b[n]);b&&((p=d.parentNode).removeChild(d),p.insertBefore(d,b))}('previousSibling',document.getElementById('mydiv'))`</sup></sub>

Answer (score -1):

Can you use my example:

```
var content = jQuery('.chapter-list').html();
jQuery('#mydiv').append(content);
// you can use prepend() place to append
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vk90pfrb/

Comment: Extracting and manipulating HTML as strings is undesirable for a number of reasons, two of which being that doing so will discard event listeners and I believe it is slower.

Answer (score -1):

Please check following code on jsfillde http://jsfiddle.net/f9z7m7y7/

```
var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
var list = document.getElementById("chapter-list");
var newItem = document.createElement("div");
list.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, list);
newItem.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
newItem.id = "mydiv";
```

Comment: As I’ve noted on a few of the other answers here, touching the HTML content is not the right way to go, as it removes all the attached event listeners.

Comment: in this case you can use a totally different technique .. you can play with position and adjust the position from javascript which will give you the same effect that element move above the list items .. but in actual you are playing with position:absolute and top property..

Comment: You could, but that’s silly when you could just reorder the elements.